# Count how many times a part of a key appears in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, tuples

I have the following dictionary and i want to count how many times keys appear, dictionary is very big.

```
a = { (1,2):3, (1,3):5, (2,1):6 }
```

and I want this result

```
1: 3 times
2: 2 times
3: 1 time
```

Comment: keys can only appear once. You are counting something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = { (1,2):3, (1,3):5, (2,1):6 }
>>> 
>>> Counter(j for k in a for j in k)
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Comment: Every time I write this particular comprehension (flattening one) I need to stop for a while and think about the order of `j`s, `k`s and `a`s :) Still, very nice solution.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*a.keys()))
```

Alternatively:

```
collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a.keys()))
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of this.  Did not know about `collections.Counter`

Comment: Way to trounce mine with `collections.Counter`! Wish I had thought of that. Also, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` would denecessitate the use of `*`

Comment: ``itertools.chain.from_iterable()`` is definitely preferable to the generator expression.

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools` and `collections.defaultdict`

```
In [43]: a={(1,2):3,(1,3):5,(2,1):6}

In [44]: counts = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [45]: for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(a.keys()):
   ....:     counts[k] += 1
   ....:     

In [46]: for k in counts:
    print k, ": %d times" %counts[k]
   ....:     
1 : 3 times
2 : 2 times
3 : 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
items = Counter(val[2] for val in dic.values())
```

Hope that sorts it.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.2

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain  

res = Counter(list(chain(*a)))
```

Comment: No need for `list` in there.  `Counter` will happily use any iterable.

Answer (score -1):

In Python:

```
import collections
s = collections.defaultdict(int)
for j, k in a.keys():
   s[j] += 1
   s[k] += 1
for x in s.keys():
   print x + ": " + s[x] + " times"
```